# Cannot set property createElement of #<Object> which is only a getter

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, webpack-2, react-hot-loader, preact

#### Description

What you are reporting: I am following this [set of instructions](https://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/) on how to setup React hot loarder. But when I go to step 3 where I put the patch, it breaks in to the one below.

#### Expected behavior

What you think should happen: Should work properly

#### Actual behavior

[image]

#### Environment

React Hot Loader version: next

Run these commands in the project folder and fill in their results:

1. `node -v`: 7.9.0
2. `npm -v`: 4.2.0

Then, specify:

1. Operating system: Windows 10
2. Browser and version: Latest Chrome

#### Reproducible Demo

https://github.com/abarcenas29/preact-sandbox-v0/blob/wip/hot-reloader/src/main.js

branch: wip-hot-reloader

Instructions:

- `yarn`
- `yarn run postinstall`
- `yarn run start:dev`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to post comments, so I have to write an answer which is not exactly a solution to the problem, but still...

The error you are receiving is due to `react-hot-loader/patch` requiring the actual `react` module and patching its `createElement` function with a new one.
See it here: `react-hot-loader/lib/patch.dev.js:179`

The main problem is that in the [webpack config](https://github.com/abarcenas29/preact-sandbox-v0/blob/wip/hot-reloader/webpack.config.js#L122) `react` module is resolved to `preact-compat` which apparently does not allow setting new values and so Hot Reload fails to run all together.

Hope this answers your question. Being as it is - I think hot reload will not work in that setup.

**EDIT:**
Found an easy solution.
Change the `webpack.config.js` resolve block to this, to point `react` to your own script:

```
// resolve for preact
webpack.resolve = {
  alias: {
    react: path.resolve(__dirname, 'react.js')
    // the rest goes as before
  }
}
```

Now create the `react.js` file and put this inside (change paths and names as you see fit):

```
var preact = require('preact-compat');

var react = {};
// Copy object properties to a new object which will allow react-hot-loader to do its magic
Object.keys(preact).forEach(function(key) {
    react[key] = preact[key];
});

module.exports = react;
```

And done! HMR is now working.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having suspicions of that. I'll test this theory out later and see if it is. I'll come back and award you if this was the case. Again, Thanks!!!

Comment: This is the place where the import of `react` takes place: `react-hot-loader/lib/patch.dev.js:7` and if you try setting the `createElement` property here yourself - the exact same error occurs. Good luck!

Comment: @MrA the problem was so interesting, I couldn't let it go :D Edited the answer with the code which solves your problem. HMR is now working. Cheers!

Comment: I converted my repo from preact to react and it manage to work as you had said. I tried doing your suggestion and the behavior is that every time I change something, it refreshes the page. Hence, the HMR stopped working.

Comment: It reloads the page only if you edit the `main.js` since it is a top level file containing the app component. If you edit `App.js` or any child components imported from `App.js` HMR will work properly.

However, If you are not strictly tied to `preact` than using the actual `react` is a better way to go IMHO.

Comment: Alongside `react` and `react-dom`, you could also alias `'preact-compat': 'preact-compat/dist/preact-compat'`. That would work as well.